# CopyDatatable() function not taking Table Name

Tags: c#, datatable

I am using CopyDataTable() function and takes that result to another table. The CopyDatatable gives me correct result but not carrying table name Why?
Below are examples

`Datatable dtTable = Datatable.Select("Select Statament").CopyToDataTable();`

and

```
Datatable dt = (from r in Datatable.AsEnumerable()
                where Convert.ToString(r[ColumnName]) == "20"
                select r).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: that's not a very serious problem, in fact it should be done that way, we can always give the copied datatable any name we want, but copying the name may cause some hidden problem if you add both original and copied ones to the same dataset.

Answer (score 0):

> The generated table returned by the method has the default table name.
>   **If you want to name the DataTable, attach it to a DataSet, or perform
>   any other DataTable specific operation, you must do so after the table
>   is created and returned**.

```
dt.TableName = YourOriginalDataTable.TableName;
```

Comment: Copy functionality gives me data and tableName but Copydatatable only returns data from table not Name. In Linq there dont have Copy() method extension but have CopyDataTable(). And even after CopyDatatable().Copy() not giving Table Name.